# Number of Detected Misprints Independent of Undetected Ones

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows:

> Suppose the number of misprints in a page is given by $M \sim \mathrm{Pois}(\lambda)$. A proofreader detects each misprint (independent of the other ones) with probability $p\in [0,1]$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables denoting the number detected and undetected misprints, respectively. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I can show this by calculation without much effort. However, I cannot grasp this result intuitively. It seems to me that a big $X$ should certainly reduce $Y$? Does there exist some property/result/analogy/intuition of the Poisson distribution that can shed some light on this result?

Comment: One could also argue that $X$ found misprints suggest a total of $M=\frac X p$ and so we expect $Y=(1-\frac1p)X$ to *grow* with $X$. Intuition can easily go wrong in probability theory (as exemplified by too diametrically opposite intuitions here)

Comment: My intuition  based on forays into proofreading is is, no matter how many errors you find, there are a zillion (or more) unfound ones.  So it seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Is it OK for you if I close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846051)? That's not about an intuitive grasp, but in the last paragraph of my answer I do suggest one.