# Conditional expectation of typos

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I'm wondering how one could solve this problem:
A text consists of $n$ characters, each of which is a typo with probability $p$ (independently).
A proof reader then reads through the text and discovers each typo (independently of the other characters) with probability $q$.
Let $T$ be the number of typos and let $C$ be the number of typos which the proof reader was able to find. Then what are $\mathbb{E}[T|C]$ and $\mathbb{E}[C|T]$ equal to?
I think it's a good idea to to view $C,T$ as random variables, write $T$ as a sum of found+not found typos and then split the conditional expectation in the first example but beyond that I'm a bit out of ideas. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  working it out explicitly for small $n$ might be a good place to start.

Comment: Should say:  not sure the rules are clear.  The way I read it, the rules are "for each typo, the proofreader reports TYPO with probability $q$, independent of all other trials, and for each non-typo the machine *never* reports TYPO."  Is that what you intended?  You don't actually say anything about what the machine does for non-typos, so I just guessed at that.

Comment: Amazing coincidence – just a few minutes ago I was linking to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846051) in answering another question.

Comment: hint: think about the probability of any individual letter (which wasn't a caught typo) being an uncaught typo.

Comment: @lulu Yes, that's how it's meant.